# Lucene WordDelimiterFilter - leading zeros

Tags: solr, lucene

Using `WordDelimiterFilter` with `generateNumberParts` I am able to take a string like "123-456" and index it such that a query for "123" will match.

What I'd like to do also is treat leading zeros like another part-generating transition.  In other words, "000123" should generate "123" as a token as well as "000123", as if I had started with "000-123" instead.

I can strip leading zeros with `PatternReplaceFilter`, but what I really want to do is *split* the string after the leading zeros, not just throw them away.

What's a good way to do this?

Would it be easier to hack PatternReplaceFilter to also index the original token if the filter actually results in modification?  Or to hack WordDelimiterFilter to acknowledge leading zeros?

Comment: instead of removing, try replacing the leading 000 with 000- so that 000123 would change to 000-123 and leave the rest of the analysis as is, which should match your situation.

Comment: Is there a way to do that such that ABC000123 would still come out as ABC000-123?  Perhaps just a matter of getting the right regexp?  (Instead of `^0+`, `[^1-9]0+[1-9]` - does that look right?)

Comment: Not sure. but you can try <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="000" replacement="000-" replace="all" />